# how to determine a number in a range?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given ranges like  0..5.....20....25..40...50......100, I have to determine which range a number is in. So the question is what's the quickest way to determine which range a number is in, like aNum = 56 is in range 50....100. after determine the range, I will assign the start num of range to aNum, which is 50 in this case. so at last, aNum = 50.

I just wonder if it can cost constant time O(1) to to it.

Any suggesions would be appreciated. Any data structure you can use to do it.

Comment: So, your ranges are not of the same size? My suggestion would be to use a case structure, like so: http://cupsofcocoa.com/2010/11/14/extension-5-the-switch-statement/

Comment: Use an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) to store ranges. Not `O(1)`, but searches will be of `O(log(no. of ranges))`. I'm not sure about IOS, but boost has a pretty good implementation of interval tree.

Comment: @Vikas. Not O(1) because constant time range queries don't exist.

Comment: Is the list of ranges fixed over the time? How long is this list?

Comment: @UmNyobe, I have mentioned that clearly in the comment. It is a comment and not an answer because the reason that I don't know a constant order way to do this.

Comment: By preprocessing the ranges and creating an array of the max value of the max interval, a *query* can be done in `O(1)`.

Comment: @Vikas: An interval tree is an overkill, a sorted array will be enough, the ranges seem to be following each other, so a binary search to get the first element smaller then the number and then take the first number greater then it will have the same result with a better efficiency and much simpler.

Comment: @UmNyobe: well, there's an `O(1)` lookup with lots of extra space and preprocessing required: create an array with 101 entries, each containing the start number of the range that value belongs to.

Comment: @amit, if the range is static, then yes. But that part is not clear from OP's question.

Comment: @Vikas: Even if not static, the power of interval trees is because it handles intersections well, where in here - it seems you have none - so any ordered search Data structure (sorted array, BST, skip list,...) will do, and will be simpler IMO.

Comment: Also note: The more general problem ("ranges" are not continuous, it could be 1-5,10-20 in the same set) is solveable by disjoint set data structure, and you can attach complete sets efficiently if needed. (but it is an overkill if the data is static and/or continious ranges)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the types of ranges shown (divisible by 5) the following algorithm is good:

1. segment all the ranges by 5 (so, for example 25-40 is actually 3 ranges: 25-29, 30-34, and 35-39.
2. Make a lookup array that keys segment to range. So, for example, if range 25-39 is #4, and segment 25-29 is #15, 30-34 is #16, and 35-39 is #17. Then lookup[15] = 4, lookup[16]=4, lookup[17]=4, etc.
3. Now it is a problem of division. Divide the number by 5 to get D, then the range # = lookup[D].

If your ranges are irregular and cannot be divisible by a common number, then a lookup table with all possible values can be created at the expense of memory.

This is a linear time algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are `N` ordered ranges, the target range could be found in `O(Log N)` using a binary search algorithm. Less than that would not be possible. For example, you can consider a case in which all ranges are equal such as:

```
1..2..3..4.. .. 99..100
```

In this case, finding the target range is equivalent to finding the number in a sorted array which cannot be done in `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample algorithm:

1. Determine the number of ranges and minimum and maximum values for each range.
2. Iterate through all of the ranges and compare the number to the minimum and maximum values for each range.
3. If it is in any of the ranges, set it equal to the minimum value of that range.
4. If it is not in any range, do whatever is needed.

The following code illustrates an example of implementing this algorithm in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*We assume there is a fixed number of ranges*/
#define RANGE_COUNT 4

int main(int argc, char** argv){
   /*Set the minimum and maximum values for each range*/
   int ranges[RANGE_COUNT][2] = {{0, 5}, {20, 20}, {25, 40}, {50, 100}};
   int x = 0, num = 0;

   /*In this example, we are using the command-line for input*/
   if(argc != 2){
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <number>", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
   }

   /*We need to ensure that the input is a number*/
   if(!(num = atoi(argv[1])) && argv[1][0] != '0'){
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: \"%s\" is not a number", argv[1]);
      exit(1);
   }

   /*See if the number is in any of the ranges*/
   for(x = 0; x < RANGE_COUNT; x++){
      if(num >= ranges[x][0] && num <= ranges[x][1]){
         /*If the number is in a range, say which one it is*/
         printf("The number %d is in the range %d..%d\n",
            num, ranges[x][0], ranges[x][1]);

         /*Set the number equal to the minimum value of the range it is in*/
         num = ranges[x][0];
         printf("num = %d\n", num);
         exit(0);
      }
   }

   /*If the number is not in any of these ranges, indicate that it is not*/
   printf("The number %d is not in any of these ranges\n", num);

   return 0;
}
```